# Undefined value in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is a method which should map the values received from a  web service call to client-side objects. I am able to map the object I receive from the web service but I want to access some of its value to perform some operation. However I am getting an undefined value.

```
LoadMarketItem(page : number) {
    this._pagination = [];
    this.DashBoardservice.GetMarketListCall(page).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.listMarket = data; 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.listMarket));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.listMarket.TotalPage));
            for(var i = 1; i <= 1; i++){
                this._pagination.push(new PaginationViewModel(i));
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this._pagination));
        },
        err => { console.log(err); });
}
```

Here is the view model

```
export class MarketViewModel 
{
    public isSuccess: boolean;
    public message : string;
    public successMessage : string;
    public exceptionErrorMessage : string;
    public errorCode: number;
    public data: MarketListObject[];
    public totalPage : number;
}

export class MarketListObject 
{
    public marketId : number;
    public city: string;
    public cityF : string;
    public name : string;
    public nameF : string;
    public sortOrder : number;
    public isActive : boolean; 
}
```

Here is the response in the console.

[image: The response from the web service]

In the console the value of total page is undefined. I have highlighted it in red. Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be lower case.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.listMarket.totalPage));
```